# Обработка строк

Tags: c++, строки

Вот какая проблема, необходимо из строки содержащей в себе нечто вида "\x1\x2\xd\x3" вытащить все значения и пересчитать их байты.

```
std::string s= "\x1\x2\xd\x3"
const  char* y = s.c_str();
????
```

Comment: Ну, перевожу для остальных "поличить" - это укр. полiчити - пересчитать. Но что вы понимаете под "вытащить все значения"?

Comment: @Harry: Возможно, «перечислить»?

Comment: @VladD Ну, в Lingvo это все же второе значение слова :)

Comment: @Harry, я бы предположил, что это была опечатка, и должно было быть слово "получить". Возможно нужно было получить из строки символы, и для каждого символа - получить представляющие его байты

Comment: Коллеги! А давайте отложим хрустальные шары, и подождём, пока ТС сам уточнит вопрос.

Comment: @Grundy Слишком далеко "и" и "у" на клавиатуре. Ладно, пусть решает ТС, как верно :)

Comment: да на ответ то это особо и невлияет) сейчас начнутся аццкие однострочники с лямбдой)

Comment: в тексте вопроса плохие байты написаны. У байта вообще то два ниббла ("полубайта"), а не один. А поэтому возникают неопределенности. К примеру, в строке "a\x0a" два байта, три или стрка просто не валидна.

Comment: @KoVadim, g++ нормально воспринимает такую string.

Comment: Что значит *пересчитать их байты*? Допустим, вычислить сумму можно так `int sum = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
    sum += (unsigned char)s[i];
  cout << sum << '\n';` , а можно еще кучей способов, но думаю, идею доступа к каждому `char` внутри `string` Вы уловили.

Comment: @avp, Трудности перевода, и, по сути, не верная правка, которую заапрувили :)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Это то, что нужно? :)

```
void outbytes(const std::string& s)
{
    std::cout << std::setfill('0') << std::hex;
    for(unsigned char c: s)
         std::cout << "\\x" << std::setw(2) 
                   << static_cast<int>(с) << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Только `c` к unsigned char приведите, если хотите чтобы все байты только 2-мя hex-ами выводились.

Comment: @avp - не скажу про стандарт, но Visual C++ при этом начнет выводить именно символами. А вот при приведении к int - все в порядке.

Comment: Приведение к int для вывода как числа, конечно, все равно нужно. У Вас сейчас байты с отрицательным значением (например, буква 'я' в кодировке cp1251) будут выводиться как \xffffffNN (8 цифр)). Короче, надо вот так: ` ... << (int)(unsigned char)c << " ";`

Comment: Ну, или `auto` заменить на `unsigned char`.

Comment: @avp что для `signed char`, что для `unsigned char` [будет выводиться символ](http://eel.is/c++draft/ostream.inserters.character#1). Если нужен код - придется приводить [к числовым типам](http://eel.is/c++draft/ostream.formatted#ostream.inserters.arithmetic).

Comment: @StateItPrimitive не поможет. на `int` тогда уж. Имеется в виду, если `static_cast` убрать вовсе из кода.

Comment: @alexolut Судя по всему _avp_ предлагал вариант при котором `static_cast<int>` остается, просто до него будет приведение к `unsigned char` (а я в своем комментарии имел в виду, что можно сразу `singed char` приводить к `unsigned char` за счет типа переменной `c`, чтобы потом не кастовать в лишний раз).

Comment: Внес исправления, спасибо всем подсказавшим!

Comment: @Harry просто `auto` заменить на `int` будет элегантнее. Без `static_cast` вообще. Ну и до кучи добавить нужные хедеры. А ещё `std::endl` заменить на `"\n"`. Да и потоковый объект хорошо бы как параметр оформить :) В общем, нет предела совершенству.

Comment: @alexolut VC++ 2015 - не работает.

Comment: @Harry в чем именно проблема? У меня в VS2015 выполнилось на ура. Да и в [онлайне пашет](http://rextester.com/TBU89475). Хотя, я вот сейчас прочитал вопрос ТС и мне кажется, ему надо совсем другое.

Comment: @alexolut Объявить `for([unsigned] int` и убрать приведение при выводе - что с `unsigned`, что без.

Comment: @Harry у Вас какая версия? У меня Community `14.0.23107.0 D14REL`.

Comment: @alexolut, я же написал  ... << (int)(unsigned char)c << " ";`  (сначала приводим **char** к **unsigned char**, т.е. к диапазону 0 ... 255, потом к **int** *для вывода цифр, а не символа*). А проще всего так `for (unsigned char c : s)
      printf("\\x%02x ", c);`

Comment: @alexolut  "Оптимизирующий компилятор Microsoft (R) C/C++ версии 19.00.23506 для x86"      for(unsigned int c: s)
        std::cout << "\\x" << std::setw(2) << c << " ";
дает \xffff....